# Student T Test to test whether a coefficient is negative or not

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test

I probably ask a fairly simple question, but I can't figure it out on my own:

The given regression model is $Price_i = ß_1 + ß_2*Age_i + ß_3*Km + [...] $

Where $ Price_i $ represents the Price of a car given other characteristics.

I'm supposed to use the robust standard errors, perform a Student test at the 5% level to test the hypothesis if cars with lower mileage cost more...

Important to mention:

- I use R
- I run the regression in previous exercises, so I have the robust
  standard errors for all coefficients (including $ß_3$).

With this in mind, I would say that the Null Hypothesis is: $H_0: ß_3 >=0$ vs. $H_1: ß_3 < 0 $

At this point I'm not sure how the test statistic would look like. Am I on the right track or completely wrong? Thank you for any hints, tips and suggestions!

Best,

Comment: You could test $H_0$ :  $\beta_3=0$ against $H_1$ : $\beta_3<0$ using one tailed test.